# Uploading file as a modifier in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, file-uploads, expresso

I would like to have my clients upload a couple files when they add a product to the cart. I want to be able to do something similar to the print products on "missions linked.com".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the Store module works with file upload fields as product modifiers. But, here's a possible way to achieve the functionality I think you're looking for:

1. Create a "designs" channel with a file upload field and any necessary meta fields.
2. Use SafeCracker to let the user submit a "design" with uploaded file, and upon submission, redirect the user to a [URI containing the ENTRY_ID of the new entry](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#return).
3. On that page, include a [Product](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/product_tag.html) form, and pass the ENTRY_ID of the design [via [segment variable](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/url_segments.html)] into either a [modifier parameter](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/product_tag.html#inputcustom_modifier_name) or hidden [modifier field](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/product_tag.html#modifiers_variable_pair).
4. When the user adds the item to the Cart, you can now reference the design via it's unique ID, which is contained in the modifier value. You can even use an embedded template or partial to pull the data from the design entry into the [Checkout](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html) process.

Comment: Spot on! There is no way to directly upload files into the cart, so this is by far the best solution (and also allows your customers to re-order images they have previously uploaded if they want).

Comment: This is a great solution. The one potential issue I have with it is that it doesn't let my customers upload the file as part of adding the product to their cart.